# using | column -t in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I am attempting to use `| column -t` at eh end of a df command in a simple script, and I keep getting an error.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
CMD=`df -Pi | column -t`
echo $CMD
```

this is the output that happens when I run it:

> Filesystem Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on /dev/mapper/rootvg-root
>   327680 149683 177997 46% / tmpfs 3851091 1 3851090 1% /dev/shm
>   /dev/sda1 99568 62 99506 1% /boot /dev/mapper/rootvg-home 131072 1457
>   129615 2% /home /dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp 131072 51 131021 1% /tmp
>   /dev/mapper/rootvg-local 65536 97 65439 1% /usr/local
>   /dev/mapper/rootvg-var 131072 5359 125713 5% /var
>   /dev/mapper/rootvg-log 132464 1535 130929 2% /var/log
>   /dev/mapper/rootvg-audit 65536 16 65520 1% /var/log/audit
>   /dev/mapper/optvg-opt 3276800 216348 3060452 7% /opt

It's all 1 big blob. I'm assuming I'm missing some wrapping characters to the actual command, but I haven't been able to find anything.

This is the output I am looking for from a script:

```
Filesystem                Inodes   IUsed   IFree    IUse%  Mounted         on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root   327680   149683  177997   46%    /
tmpfs                     3851091  1       3851090  1%     /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                 99568    62      99506    1%     /boot
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home   131072   1457    129615   2%     /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp    131072   51      131021   1%     /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootvg-local  65536    97      65439    1%     /usr/local
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var    131072   5359    125713   5%     /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-log    132464   1535    130929   2%     /var/log
/dev/mapper/rootvg-audit  65536    16      65520    1%     /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/optvg-opt     3276800  216353  3060447  7%     /opt
```

Comment: You have to quote `$CMD`.

Comment: @shellter I disagree.

Comment: double quotes worked, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the pipe "|":

```
CMD=`df -Pi | column -t`
echo "$CMD"
```

But, something tells me this isn't what you wanted either.

Comment: That was a typo that's now fixed.

Comment: As @BenjaminW. said, include the double quotes around "$CMD"

Comment: This worked, Thank you!

Comment: When I say this, I should say that the double quotes around the $CMD worked to give me what I needed. the pipe was already there, I just fat fingered the question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap your echo in double quotations. So it respects the spaces,newlines, etc.

```
echo "$CMD"
```